# Cannot drag and drop in nautilus

Tags: nautilus, 18.04

When I click a file (or selection of files) in nautilus (Files) and start a drag, only the selection rectangle happens - the files stay put.

As seen here - I expect the file to move but instead others are selected.

[image: screencast]

Comment: (not related to the question) Can you tell me what is that theme in the gif?

Comment: @ApoorvPotnis https://github.com/horst3180/arc-theme/